# What is the best way to make animation from 100 image frame in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

In Unity i want to make an animation Map.
I have created a animation map with 100 frame image.

The animation image size total is too large for android games.
And if i using animation in unity it will take a time to sort the image record one by one and of course it will result in large size.

What is the best way to make animation for 100 frame images in Unity ?

Thanks
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial using sprite sheet animation without particle system:
http://www.strandedsoft.com/using-spritesheets-with-unity3d/

Comment: Is there any free software can generate a sprite sheet ? texturepacker is not free. What i want to make is a map with with 100 frame. Is too big. Do you have any best solution for animated the background map ?

Answer (score 0):

try "Texture Sheet Animation Module" of Particle System to cast one particle with texture sheet animations:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysTexSheetAnimModule.html

Comment: How to use it ? Could you give me some tutorial ? Thanks